# VS-Code on Fedora 29 - Ignores Settings and Extensions

Tags: linux, fedora, visual-studio-code

I just setup fresh installation of Fedora29 and wanted to use VS-Code. I installed everything according by the book (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux)

and VSCode itsself is starting just fine. However when I install extensions or change some user settings (in this case the font family) VSCode completely ignores this.

It does not throw errors or anything. The extensions appear as installed settings are in the json as well but still. Does not effect the behaviour of VSCode

Would be great if someone had an idea what I need to do to get this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it was basically 2 things. With the fonts it was just a resart that was missing (I had just installed them).

Concerning the Extensions (in my case it was the Material Icons and another Color Scheme) it was this. In Windows if you download the Theme it also gets applied automatically (or at least it was when I installed it on my windows machine back then). In Fedora I had to set it manually. So if you are having the same problems with the Themes go to your settings and make sure e.g workbench.iconTheme and workbench.colorTheme are set as at least in my case it wasn't done automatically.

**settings.json**

```
{
  "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
  "workbench.colorTheme": "One Dark Theme"
}
```